# Make first row in Google Spreadsheet column names

Tags: google-sheets

I cannot figure out how to turn the first row of a Google Spreadsheet into column names so that I can sort the spreadsheet by column without losing the variable names at the top of the spreadsheet.

I mean that I want to sort by column without losing the column names, which are currently stored in the first row.

Comment: Are you talking about just having filtering turned on? It adds the drop-down list in the top row so you can show/hide groups of items.

Answer (score 1):

- Select your table range.
- Right click on the range, select "Sort Range".
- Then select "Data has header row" and define your sorting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To lock the first row, go to the upper left corner of the spreadsheet where the number column meets the letter row. Drag the bottom of that cell down and you'll see a line appear. Drag it below the first row and it will be locked.

Now it shouldn't change if you try to sort, and it will always display as you scroll through your document.

Comment: I already have this. I need to sort based on multiple columns, when I select all and sort based on two columns it still sorts the first row with the variable names.